# How I stop the incoming call when I am talking SIP ANDROID

Tags: android, sip, sip-server

actually I have this code on Android :

file IncomingCallReceiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
        try {
            SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
                    try {
                        call.answerCall(30);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            WalkieTalkieActivity wtActivity = (WalkieTalkieActivity) context;
            incomingCall = wtActivity.manager.takeAudioCall(intent, listener);
            incomingCall.answerCall(30);
            incomingCall.startAudio();
            incomingCall.setSpeakerMode(true);
            if (incomingCall.isMuted()) {
                incomingCall.toggleMute();
            }
            wtActivity.call = incomingCall;
            wtActivity.updateStatus(incomingCall);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (incomingCall != null) {
                incomingCall.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

file for make calls

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                        EditText textField = (EditText)
                                                (textBoxView.findViewById(R.id.calladdress_edit));
                                        sipAddress = textField.getText().toString();
                                        initiateCall();
                                    }
```

function for start streaming of audio

```
public void initiateCall() {
        updateStatus(sipAddress);
        try {
            SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
                // Much of the client's interaction with the SIP Stack will
                // happen via listeners.  Even making an outgoing call, don't
                // forget to set up a listener to set things up once the call is established.
                @Override
                public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                    call.startAudio();
                    call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                    call.toggleMute();
                    updateStatus(call);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                    updateStatus("Ready.");
                }
            };
            call = manager.makeAudioCall(me.getUriString(), sipAddress, listener, 30);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity", "Error when trying to close manager.", e);
            if (me != null) {
                try {
                    manager.close(me.getUriString());
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity",
                            "Error when trying to close manager.", ee);
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (call != null) {
                call.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

but now I need stop the incoming call when I am talking whit any extension, I am using the server freeswitch and sip library of android.
please could you help me ?

thanks.